# ASP NET SqlException: Incorrect Syntax

Tags: sql, asp.net, sql-server

I have a method in my ASP NET webpage to execute a SQL command. When I execute the following command I am getting

> SqlException was unhandled by user code

The SQL error is

> Incorrect syntax near Chemicals'

Here is the SQL command string:

```
SELECT MainHeading 
FROM Areas 
INNERJOIN Chemicals ON Areas.AreaNo = Chemicals.AreaNo 
WHERE (Chemicals.IDMark = @item)
```

Where `@item` is a session variable.

The simplified tables are as follows

[image]

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You missed a space between `innerjoin`

```
SELECT MainHeading 
FROM Areas 
INNER JOIN Chemicals ON Areas.AreaNo = Chemicals.AreaNo 
WHERE (Chemicals.IDMark = @item)
```

Comment: Wow. I knew I was missing something obvious, but that's embarrassing. Many thanks, juergen!

Answer (score 2):

It must be:

```
SELECT MainHeading FROM Areas INNER JOIN Chemicals ON Areas.AreaNo = Chemicals.AreaNo WHERE (Chemicals.IDMark = @item)
```

`INNER JOIN` were two words :)

As an information for you, `INNER JOIN` is the same as `JOIN`.